# swap both user input and database to lowercase before comparing

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to find a way to "collect all the classes from a selected date to another, managed by a specific teacher", and so far, its going okay. I have used to uppercase to match with a capital letter as the first one in the name... but since some teachers (McGonnagal) for example is having capital letters in her lastname, is there a way to, say , get the input to lowercase,  and also transfer the data in the database (McGonnagal) all to lowercase?

So it would always be a match even if the user inserted McGoNNaGal in the program.... anyone got any ideas?`

```
 try {

        String lararesNamn = txtLoCLarare.getText();
        String LFN = lararesNamn.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+lararesNamn.substring(1);
        String datumFrom = txtLoCfom.getText();
        String datumTom = txtLoCtom.getText();
        String lararesEN = txtLarareEN.getText();
        String LEN = lararesEN.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+lararesEN.substring(1);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listOfClasses = databas.fetchRows("SELECT KURSNAMN FROM KURS JOIN LARARE ON KURSLARARE = LARAR_ID WHERE KURSSTART >= " + "'" + datumFrom + "'" + " AND KURSSLUT <= " + "'" + datumTom + "'" + " AND(LARARE.FORNAMN = " + "'" + LFN + "'" + " AND LARARE.EFTERNAMN = " + "'" + LEN + "'" + ")");
                System.out.println(listOfClasses);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, listOfClasses);
    } catch(InfException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Best regards!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: firebird database

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the fetched name from SQL DB to lower or upper case. For LOWER case modify your query to.

```
SELECT KURSNAMN FROM KURS JOIN LARARE ON KURSLARARE = LARAR_ID WHERE KURSSTART >= " + "'" + datumFrom + "'" + " AND KURSSLUT <= " + "'" + datumTom + "'" + " AND(LOWER(LARARE.FORNAMN) = " + "'" + LFN + "'" + " AND LOWER(LARARE.EFTERNAMN) = " + "'" + LEN + "'" + ")"
```

You can use UPPER function for upper case

Comment: thanks! I will try it out. 

Do you know any way to get an output if the variable is NOT matched in the database? now im using "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, listOfClasses);" , but if "listOfClasses" is empty, i want it to say "no match found".